# Question deleted as abandoned although I didn't abandon it

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543004/swap-vanished-after-reboot)
 a while ago. It didn't receive any helpful attention, not even a comment asking for output of some command or something, or suggesting what I could look at. Since I still have the problem that is described there, I am still waiting for some reaction, although I do realise that at this point it's very unlikely.

Nevertheless, I have been using this question regularly to look up how to redo my swap after each reboot.

Now, however, I found that is has been deleted as abandoned. I feel that as I am still using it, and as the problem is still active, it should not have been deleted as abandoned.

What should I do? I would really love to have this problem solved somehow. Asking the same question again seems weird.

Answer (score 3):

You've done the right thing, asking in here. I have undeleted it.

If it's still a pressing issue, you might want to consider putting a bounty on it.